# Dpkg error whe I try to upgrade nessus on ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, dpkg, nessus

When I run this command `sudo dpkg -i Nessus-5.0.1-ubuntu1110_amd64.deb`, I got the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing Nessus-5.0.1-ubuntu1110_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Would anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: try typing `sudo apt-get install -f` in terminal (no package required), this should force the uninstalled dependencies and fix the error

Comment: It looks like the file is not there. Is it really there? I'd fire up a new instance of terminal, make sure it is there with `ls`, and then also it might be useful to add `./`: `sudo dpkg -i ./Nessus-5.0.1-ubuntu1110_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 1):

First, try to [check the checksums](http://www.ehow.com/how_8714677_calculate-checksum-procedures.html) and make sure you got a complete correct download.

Second, try to run the command with `--force-architecture` argument:

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i Nessus-5.0.1-ubuntu1110_amd64.deb
```

This should work.